# Batch file to generate files

Tags: batch-file

Ok, I am trying to make a batch file to generate a series of files and folders, but can't find on how to do it.

My Idea:

```
FOR /f "Tokens=* delims=" %%I IN (export2.csv) DO call:create %%I GOTO:EOF

:create ECHO 1 >>%~pd0%1
```

But it didn't work at all.

Comment: typo in second line. should be `%~dp0%1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out a little bit ago and here is what I ended up with. It will generate both the path and create an empty file with the name of the file listed in the masterlist.csv.

Source Code

```
@ECHO OFF
CHDIR "%~dp0"
SET Count=0
ECHO/ Generating Necessary File, please Wait...
FOR /F %%A IN (Masterlist.csv) DO CALL:MKDIR %%A
EXIT /B

:MKDIR
SET /A Count+=1
SET "Path=%~dp1"
SET "File=%~nx1"
IF NOT EXIST "%Path%" MKDIR "%Path%
IF NOT EXIST "%Path%" CALL:ERROR "Path"
IF NOT EXIST "%Path%\%File%" ECHO/ >>"%Path%\%File%"
IF NOT EXIST "%Path%\%File%" CALL:ERROR
EXIT /B

:ERROR
IF NOT EXIST "Errorlog.csv" ECHO Error, Line Count>>Errorlog.csv
ECHO %~1, Line %Count%>>Errorlog.csv
```

A few example lines from Masterlist.csv

```
2006\MS06-003\Office2000\office2000-kb892842-fullfile-enu.exe
2006\MS06-003\Office2003\office2003-kb892843-fullfile-enu.exe
2006\MS06-003\Office2003\WinSec-MS06-003-009-P44333-outlook2003-kb892843-fullfile-enu.exe
2006\MS06-003\OfficeXP\officexp-kb892841-fullfile-enu.exe
2006\MS06-006\WindowsMedia-KB911564-x86-ENU.exe
2006\MS06-007\2003\WindowsServer2003-KB913446-x86-ENU.exe
2006\MS06-007\XP\WindowsXP-KB913446-x86-ENU.exe
2006\MS06-012\2003\office2003-KB905756-FullFile-ENU.exe
2006\MS06-015\2000\Windows2000-KB908531-x86-ENU.EXE
2006\MS06-015\2003\WindowsServer2003-KB908531-x86-ENU.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I have no idea how your data file looks like it's hard to give good advice here, but your code could be cleaned up a bit:

```
set "filepath=%~dp0"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%I in (export2.csv) do call :create "%%I"
rem This is needed to avoid stepping into the subroutine again
goto :eof

:create
rem This will create an empty file instead of one that contains a single line with 1
copy nul "%filepath%%~1"
goto :eof
```

This won't create any directories, though. You can create those with `md`.

Comment: Yea the issue with the way i did it was the fact that it didnt create directories which is what i needed.

Comment: `mkdir`/`md` can create a complete directory tree if it doesn't yet exist. This should be easy to integrate.